# PYSide/PyQt Qtreewidget font color

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I was wondering how can I change the QtreewidgetItem font color to something else than the predefined Qt colors. I want to use hex color code instead, any ideas?

```
QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.setForeground(0,QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just explicitly instantiate a `QColor` object with the desired color:

```
my_item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
my_item.setForeground(0,QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("#123456")))
```